# Страница пользователя и Новостная лента событий

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Привет! ломаю голову, помогите собрать базу.

есть к примеру такая структура 3'х таблиц 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне нужно сделать страницу пользователя (таблица user_page)
куда записываются его активность/события. т.е. загрузил фото, добавил видео, создал группу и т.п.

решил записывать в таблицу ИД юзера, тип события, и ИД события.
Далее встает вопрос: как выводить инфу?
можно было бы сделать через join но информация разная в таблице видео 5 ячеек а в фото 6. и потом фото и видео этим не ограниченно! будут еще репосты записей, кто то напишет на стене. вообщем все как ВК устроенно по сути.
Мне предлагают без джоинов сперва сделать запрос на события а после второй запрос выводить инфу события. за 50 событий 50 запросов.
Либо еще вариант предложили сперва выводить все события собрать их в массив с ИДшниками событий после чего собрать все события по типу запросить инфу и после отсортировать по времени уже на PHP.

Как все таки правильно реализовать такую схему?

на сервере мускул. как собрать архитектуру страницу пользователя и ленту событий не могу сообразить. помогите кто чем может.

Comment: в соцсетях это реализовано на NoSql БД

Comment: ВК например использует обе базы. Mysql и своя база думаю она у них как раз NoSql. работают в связке.

Answer (score 0):

Не нравится мне идея с JOIN - поскольку могут появляться дополнительные события, то универсальный запрос написать не удастся - нужно будет вносить правки. Так что лучше сначала запрос по таблице логов, и запросы к каждому типу таблиц с событиями. Можно собрать ид для каждого типа события и сделать один запрос на каждый непустой массив ид.

Comment: ну как я и писал что мне предложили такой вариант. собрать все типы событий. не по числу событий, а по числу типов. собрали массив с типами и туда их ИДшники. потом делаем запрос where id in (...) собрали инфу и раскидали по дате/врмени.
в этом случае не нужно делать запрос на каждый тип события